# Qt Slot Testing

Tags: c++, qt, testing, signals-slots

I'm writing some test cases for a Qt5 GUI app.  I use `QObject::findChild` to check wether a element exists and `QSignalSpy` to check that its signals are called with the right arguments.  Now I want to check that the signals are connected to the right slots but I don't see how to do that.  I would have supposed this to be some fairly standard thing to do but I couldn't find anything about it on the net.

I put a small demo app in the appendix explaining what I want.  It consists just of a slider in a main window and a test case where the slider is found and changed.  I would like to continue to test if `w.doSomething(10)` was called and I would like to check if `slider->valueChanged(10)` was the caller.

I see basically three possible ways for this:

1. Use a standard Qt testing tool/best practice I havn't found yet.  (Any hints appreciated.)
2. Find the table where Qt stores the connections `sender->*signal` to `receiver->*slot` and verify that (slightly abusing syntax)

   ```
   sender == slider && signal == &QSlider::valueChanged;
   receiver == &w && slot == &MainWindow::doSomething;
   ```
3. Write a wrapper for `MainWindow::doSomething(int)` that reads:

   ```
   void doSomething(int value) {
       slotCallTable << this << "MainWindow::doSomething(int)" << value;
       doSomething_nowReally(value);
   }
   ```

   where `slotCallTable` records the call which I can hopefully verify somehow in `Test::test()`.  There I would like to check if the receiver is the right object.  But I think I can't verify the sender this way (wouldn't be a big problem).

Can anyone tell me if (1) exists, if (2) is possible/reasonable or if anyone has already done something similar to (3) that I don't have to start as zero?

Note that I have the code for the app I'm testing but I can't modify it by hand since the tests must be automatically reproducible and the testing code shall not go into the main development codebase.  However, programmable changes of the code would be OK as long as they are (robustly) reproducible.

Thank you for reading all the long post and thank you really really much if you can (and do) also answer some of my questions.

Cheers
imix

#### Appendix (working example):

`// window.h:`

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSlider>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QSlider * slider;

private slots:
    void doSomething(int value) {}

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        slider = new QSlider(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal, this);
        slider->setObjectName("slider");
        QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                         this, SLOT(doSomething(int)));
        this->show();
    }

    ~MainWindow() { delete slider; }
};
```

`// test.h:`

```
#include <QtTest>
#include "window.h"

class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    MainWindow w;

private slots:
    void test() {
        QSlider * slider = w.findChild<QSlider *>("slider");
        QVERIFY(slider != nullptr); // slider exists

        QSignalSpy spy(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)));
        QCOMPARE(spy.isValid(), true); // signal exists
            // note: of course it exists here, but this
            //       would be a custom signal in real

        slider->setValue(10); // fire some signal

        QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1);                    // fired exactly once
        QCOMPARE(spy.takeFirst().at(0).toInt(), 10); // with right arguments

        QVERIFY("how to test right slot was triggered ???" && false);
    }
};
```

`// main.cc:`

```
#include "test.h"
QTEST_MAIN(Test)
```

Comment: Hi ! Well, I don't know how to do the trick but, I have some experience in testing software and, I don't really get the interest of testing signal/slot mechanism. It's just advanced call function hidden behind this. Maybe you could perform some test at a higher level ?

Comment: You can try to make connection using `QObject:: connect` with `Qt:: UniqueConnection` and check if return value is valid. If it is invalid then the connection has already existed. It can change application state though, so it's not ideal for unit testing.

Comment: Rather than testing that the slot is called, why not test that the MainWindow class does what you expect it to when the signal is emitted?  You may also want to investigate using a mocking framework for C++ such as Google Mock.

Comment: If you are willing to spend money you could also look at test frameworks such as Frog Logic's Squish, they have mechanisms to test that signals are being called.

Comment: @Martin: I don't want to test the signal/slot mechanism -- I'm very confident it works as expected ;-)  I just want to test that the signals and slots are wired up correctly.  Sorry for the confusion.  I shortened the test case to better reflect that.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: That's a small step forward.  I can check that the signal is at least connected to something this way.  That's better than nothing.  Thanks.

Comment: @RA: Most things in my GUI work like this: Choose some parameters and click a button.  The button calls a custom slot which collects the parameters and fires a custom signal.  Depending on what the customer ordered there are now none, one, or more services starting processing.  The processing is a complicated algorithm itself and exists as already deeply tested library module.  I only want to get sure exactly the right algorithms were correctly triggered by the signal.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @RA: I have no experience in Mocking.  Do I understand it right that this aims point (3) in my list.  I can replace my slots with mocked up slots and check there if they were triggered?  Or am I totally wrong?  I will give it a close look, thanks.

Comment: @simotek: It would be possible to spend money on a testing framework.  But I already can test that signals were called.  What I need to test is which slots are triggered by the signals.

Comment: @imix You can't create mock slots, but you can create mock classes for the things that your main window class calls.  In your case, (if I understand you correctly) you can test that your main window emits the right signal when the slider emits its signal (without using a mock object), but I'd have to see the real implementation of `doSomething` to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to unit test the connections, you can use [`connect()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) with `Qt::UniqueConnection` for the last parameter.

Change the testing line to this :

```
QVERIFY( false == QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), &w, SLOT(doSomething(int)), Qt::UniqueConnection)  );
```

If the connection doesn't exist, then `connect()` returns `true`.

However, take care that it is not possible to check multiple connections (creation of the same connection more then once).

Comment: That solves the problem since I don't have multiple connections to the same slot.  PavelStrakhov did already give the same answer in his comment but I didn't get that "unique" refers indeed to the connection (well, it's written there -- I see) but thougt it's a "unique (sole) slot" for the signal.  Thanks to all!